# Function returns chars from a shrinking vector. What to return when vector is empty?

Tags: c++, vector

I am programming a board game in which random pieces have to be pulled from a bag (imagine Scrabble pieces being pulled from a bag).

I use the following function to return random chars (which represent pieces) from a vector (which represents the bag):

```
vector<char> pieces = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};

char pullPiece() {
    int randomIndex = rand() % pieces.size();
    char c = pieces[randomIndex]; // Get the piece
    pieces.erase(pieces.begin() + randomIndex); // Remove the piece
    return c;
}
```

After the char is retrieved, it's erased from the vector. The function then returns the char that was retrieved.

**What's the best way to handle a call to `pullPiece()` when the vector `pieces` has had all of its elements removed and is empty?**

The only thing I can think of is throwing an exception, but since this will happen every time my game is played, it doesn't really seem like an exception. I've also considered checking the size of the vector before calling `pullPiece()`, but I feel like I should be programming this functionality into the `pullPiece()` function itself.

Comment: You may return something that is not a valid character (like -1 or EOF). And using int instead of char for the return type (functions in the C standard library do this)

Comment: Return `\0`, or throw an exception, or change function signature, to return success flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way would be to return `\0` for the empty case.

It might be worth refactoring to return an *iterator* from the vector, rather than a `char`. You can then safely return `pieces.end()`. That's very much the C++ standard library container way of doing it. Note that you are allowed to test for an iterator being `pieces.end()` but **don't** attempt to dereference that iterator, or increment it. (You can decrement an iterator set to `pieces.end()` so long as the container is not empty).

A C-like way would be to refactor the function to return an `int`, and return `EOF` for the special value. (Cf. `isupper`, `islower` etc.)

Comment: I used your first recommendation. If this were anything more than a pet project I'd use your second. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 2):

in the new std (c++17) there is something called std::optional. meaning the return value might exist, then its just your char, otherwise there is a "invalidbit" that can be checked.
boost has a optional type as well.

you could return 0 for invalid or a negative number.

other solutions, like giving a validflag as reference and setting it work, but arent so nice i think.

Comment: Great idea re. `std::optional`. Plus one. The negative number ain't so good since `char` can be `signed` and some encodings use all 8 bits.

Comment: i think std::optional is the best fit in that scenario :)

Comment: I think though that many software stacks will wait until the mid 2020s to migrate to C++17, but you can always handcode std::optional, or use boost::optional.

Answer (score 2):

You have a function that needs to return either a char, or the information that there is no char to be returned. There are different ways:

Clean, clumsy, and inefficient: Throw an exception if there is no char to be returned.

Clean, a bit work: Have a function that tells you whether a char is available that must be called before you retrieve a char. Getting a char if none is available is a bug that must be fixed and terminates your app.

Not clean, but efficient: Define one char value to indicate "no data is available", for example '\0'. It works better in some cases than in others. It can work here because there is only a tiny subset of char values that could be returned. It often works well when you return pointers to objects, or a null pointer. It doesn't work at all if any return value could be valid.

Clean, efficient, but not in C++: Return an optional value. That's what optionals are made for. (I'm told optionals are becoming available in a new standard; use them. That's what optionals are made for).

Clean, quite efficient, slightly clumsy: Return a bool value to indicate the call succeeded. Pass a char* or char& to the function where it deposits its result (char& has the advantage that you can't pass a null pointer; char* has the advantage that it is clear in the source code that the char value is going to be modified).

Clean, quite efficient, slightly clumsy: Return a struct with a char value, and a bool indicating the char value is valid (that's practically the same as returning an optional value).

I personally prefer returning an optional value in a language that supports it. Otherwise I prefer returning a bool for success, and the value through a pointer, because it's a method that *always* works; for any kind of value.

Comment: optional is in the new standard. boost has one as well

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the vector is empty before calling the function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/empty/

Or, inside of the function, check if the vector is empty and just return \0;

Answer (score 0):

Choose for yourself:

```
char pullPiece() noexcept; // 1) precondition: Pieces must be available.
char pullPiece();          // 2) Throws, if no piece is available.
std::optional<char> pullPiece() noexcept; // 3)
```

There are different aspects to consider in a function interface:

- Is it simple?
- Is an efficient implementation possible?
- Is the intent clear? (Can I do something wrong?)

1) Obviously, when asking the client for the precondition to be satisfied, then the function itself is not bound to check it. (Even though in a debug build, an `assert()` is strongly recommended.) Therefore, interface 1) allows the most efficient implementation.

2) This is the simplest interface. However, the client programmer must read the comment in order to know how to deal with the empty case. So, can something go go wrong? Yes, it can. Is that horribly bad? Not necessarily. But I would avoid throwing exceptions as part of a normal control flow.

3) The third interface is clear. Nothing can go wrong. It's not as simple anymore, but the programmer does not need to check the documentation for the corner case. It's clear from the function signature. If the overhead of checking for emptiness isn't too much of a burden, then I would go for this solution.

Note however, that [`std::optional<T>` is only available by the C++ standard starting with C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Some compilers already [implement it in the namespace `std::experimental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional), e. g. gcc 4.9 or clang 3.4 both in C++14 mode. An alternative, that will work even with older compilers is `boost::optional<T>`.